# Why is the Python build of OpenCV (cv2.pyd) so small?

Tags: python, opencv

I wanted to use OpenCV with Python, so I downloaded OpenCV for Windows and got a folder of ~3.7GB after decompression. What surprised me was that the only file I needed was cv2.pyd, which was so small (~11MB) comparing to the C builds (~674MB). I simply copied it to my Python lib-packages folder without adding anything to my PATH and it worked perfectly.

I don't know how Python binding works, and I thought it should call C/C++ implementations under the hood. However, cv2 did not seem to require any C/C++ library. It just looks like magic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it has something to do with static linking and using all possible tricks found in ["Reducing Executable Size"](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/reducing-executable-size) or ["GCC x86 code size optimizations"](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/17/x86-gcc-code-size-optimizations)

OpenCV uses [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) as build system, which provides "MinSizeRel" build type. It seems to auto-apply most of those tricks. Couldn't find any good documentation on that, hence: [***[citation needed]***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCitation_needed)

---

*(follows my original answer which didn't quite address the actual question)*

More convenient way to get opencv for python may be to download it from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

After running installer you'll find `cv2.pyd` in `c:\python27\lib\site-packages`

As far as we are concerned `.pyd` file is same as `.dll`: http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll

Which means that we can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to look into it. This is what we see:

[image: cv2.pyd]

This picture means that `cv2.pyd` is dynamically linked against opencv libraries which contain actual functionality. These take around ~45MB of disk space.

Comment: But I don't even have these OpenCV DLL files in my site-packages folder.